# Reset all values in a table to 100 using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I have this table created using SQLAlchemy.  Whenever the prtProbeSummary function is called it only resets the first record(google) for fields http200_sum, http300_sum, http400_sum and http500_sum to value 100.  I need to reset all values of those fields in all rows to 100.  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks.

```
class urlProbeSummary(url_probe_db.Model):
    name = url_probe_db.Column(url_probe_db.String(250), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    url = url_probe_db.Column(url_probe_db.String(250), nullable=False)
    http200_sum = url_probe_db.Column(url_probe_db.Integer, nullable=False)
    http300_sum = url_probe_db.Column(url_probe_db.Integer, nullable=False)
    http400_sum = url_probe_db.Column(url_probe_db.Integer, nullable=False)
    http500_sum = url_probe_db.Column(url_probe_db.Integer, nullable=False)


def prtProbeSummary(counter):

    # Empty summary table before adding new statistics as the statistics to be collected is not cumulative.  
    print(f"Clearing DB data...")

    with app.app_context():
        record_to_update = url_probe_db.session.execute(url_probe_db.select(urlProbeSummary)).scalar()
        record_to_update.http200_sum = 100
        url_probe_db.session.commit()
    
        record_to_update = url_probe_db.session.execute(url_probe_db.select(urlProbeSummary)).scalar()
        record_to_update.http300_sum = 100
        url_probe_db.session.commit()

        record_to_update = url_probe_db.session.execute(url_probe_db.select(urlProbeSummary)).scalar()
        record_to_update.http400_sum = 100
        url_probe_db.session.commit()

        record_to_update = url_probe_db.session.execute(url_probe_db.select(urlProbeSummary)).scalar()
        record_to_update.http500_sum = 100
        url_probe_db.session.commit()

prtProbeSummary(counter)
```

Output:

```
Clearing DB data...
After cleaning up - [('google', 'https://httpstat.us/200', 100, 100, 100, 100), ('yahoo', 'https://httpstat.us/401', 0, 0, 3, 0), ('pcs', 'https://httpstat.us/521', 0, 0, 0, 3)]
```

Comment: What is `url_probe_db.select()`? It's apparently only returning the first row from the query it's given.

Comment: And if it didn't return only one row, `.scalar()` would raise an exception. Why do you do that if you want all the rows?

Comment: Try a `with engine.begin() as conn:` block containing `conn.execute(url_probe_db.update(urlProbeSummary.__table__).values(http200_sum=100, http300_sum=100, …))`

Answer (score 1):

thanks for giving inspiration in the replies.  I got it fixed by using the below statements.  Thanks.

```
from sqlalchemy import desc, update

    with app.app_context():
        stmt = (update(urlProbeSummary).values(http200_sum = 100,http300_sum = 100,http400_sum = 100,http500_sum = 100))
        url_probe_db.session.execute(stmt)
        url_probe_db.session.commit()
```